# Multiple regression won't work: Residuals: ALL 349 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom

Tags: r, linear-regression

I did some simple regressions based on this excel file and they all worked fine. But I tried doing a  multiple regression but it somehow didn't work anymore.
This part of my code:

```
dsZonderNa <- na.omit(dsAfrika)
```

I saw it had a value of n.s. in some row so I deleted that row as well by:

```
dsZonderNa <- dsZonderNa[-c(343),]
```

I thought that was the problem but it still didn't work when I tried this:

```
MRtobin <- lm(dsZonderNa$ProfMarg ~ dsZonderNa$`R&D%-3`+dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`)
summary(MRtobin)
```

The results I get are pretty weird. It gives me a lotttt of rows that are like this:

```
Residuals:
ALL 349 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
                                                Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                      4.85100         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`R&D%-3`                              0.62500         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`0.59399999999999997   1.88738         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`0.62                 -6.43700         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`0.65600000000000003  -4.06600         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`0.65900000000000003   1.90100         NA      NA
dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`0.79300000000000004  -1.15300         NA      NA
```

and at the end it says:

```
Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 348 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

I looked up some stuff on internet and it may be that rows aren't numeric but they are as I tried all the columns with is.factor() and they all returned false.

I don't really how to solve this, if I take away the AvgCost/OpRev variable it works but as soon as I use that one, I get the weird output. So the problem lies probably in that column but I don't know where as I checked the column and it only contained numeric values as far as I could see.

Hopefully someone knows what I should do.

Comment: Can you show the output of `dput(head(dsZonderNa, 10))`?

Comment: Try dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev` <- as.numeric(dsZonderNa$`CostEmpl/OPRev`) and then run the model

Comment: when you read in the table, because of "n.s" or some other string in this column, AvgCost/OpRev is now a factor or a string, you can check by doing ```class(dsZonderNa$CostEmpl/OPRev)```. You need to ensure it all numbers, then do ```dsZonderNa$CostEmpl/OPRev = as.numeric(as.character(dsZonderNa$CostEmpl/OPRev))```

Comment: I tried doing that but it gives me the error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one